# Error by sending a Mail with PHP

Tags: php

I´m trying to send email to all students from database base but its giving an error.

This is my php code,its giving an error:

> (Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in )on line number 15,

Can any one solve this?

```
<?php
$connection= new mysqli("localhost", "id1004807_m_muntazir313", "hater007", "sms");
if($connection){ echo "connected";} else { echo "Sorry";}
ini_set('SMTP','myserver');
ini_set('smtp_port',25);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
 $name=$_POST["name"];
 $email=$_POST["email"];
 $subject=$_POST["subj"];
 $comment=$_POST["comments"];

$sql="SELECT email_name FROM email";
$RS = $connection->query($sql);
while($rw = $RS->fetch_assoc()){
echo $rw["email_name"];
 $to= $rw["email_name"];
$headers="From: $name<$email>";
 $messege="Name:$name \n\nEmail:$email \n\n Subject:$subject\n\nMessege:$comment";

 if(mail($to,$subject,$messege,$headers)){

    echo"Email sent";
 }else{
        echo "Please try again";
 }
}}

?>
```

Comment: Don't mix `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*`

Comment: You don't have mysql_fetch_assoc on mysqli, you want $RS->fetch_assoc();

Comment: now its give erro( Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in)

Comment: Are you sure your query is returning anything? Can you run SELECT email_name FROM email directly on your database to see if you get a result? Or do `if ($RS = $connection->query($sql)) { * your while loop * } else { print "No result from your query"; }`